# How to add action in modal button using ajax and php

Tags: php, ajax

How do an action if the button is in modal that has been clicked? I'm using jQuery with Ajax and PHP.

Javascript

```
$(document).on('click', '#edit', function(){
var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
var userName = $(this).attr("data-username");
var userType = $(this).attr("data-user_type");
var action = 'edit';
$.ajax({
    url:"/auth/action",
    method:"POST",
    data:{id:id, action:action},
    success:function(data)
    {
        $('#editModal').modal('show');
        $('#userName').val(userName);
        $('#userType').val(userType);
        $('#id').val(id);
    }
})
  });
```

PHP

```
if($_POST["action"] == 'edit')
{
    $statement = $connect->prepare(
        "UPDATE users SET username = :username, user_type = :user_type WHERE id = :id"
    );
    $result = $statement->execute(
        array(
            ':userName' =>  $_POST["username"],
            ':userType' =>  $_POST["user_type"],
            ':id'           =>  $_POST["id"]
        )
    );
    if(!empty($result))
    {
        echo 'Data Updated';
    }
}
```

Modal HTML

```
            <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Edit User</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <form method="post" action="">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="userName" class="col-form-label">Username:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control border-danger" id="userName" readonly style="background-color: #2A3038">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="userType" class="col-form-label">User Type:</label>
                        <select class="form-control border-success" id="userType">
                        <option value="user">User</option>
                        <option value="contributor">Contributor</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                  <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id">
                  <input type="hidden" id="operation" name="operation">
                    <button type="button" id="update" name="update" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

The requests are to edit the information of the user, the problem I'm having is that the submit button in modal is not causing an action I also have checked it in the network tab in developer tools.

Comment: can you share your HTML code, most likly you have multiple `#edit`'s on the dom

Comment: your not posting the values only `action` and `id`, so the others will be undefined. also maybe unrelated your ajax issue but, check your binding params, they don't match.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone check the edit thank you

Comment: So you have a loop which shows all your users, and on each of the links to edit a user you use `id="edit"`? Its unclear wht your modal is doing as soon as its opened it going to POST, to a file which updates, instead it should GET, then fill in the form.. but your code is using the inputs from the current form and then putting them back into the form. Also the id, operation and update wont be sent as its outside the `<form>`

Comment: $('#update').click() event trigger Ajax

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for posting form data with ajax from modal popup window and you are unable to get it.

Here is the code to guide you and check if the solution is correct

```
    $(document).on('click', '#update', function(){
        $('#editModal').modal('show');
        var id = $("#id").val();
        var userName = $("#userType").val();
        var userType = $("#userType").val();
        alert(userType);
        var action = 'edit';
        $.ajax({
            url:"/auth/action.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{id:id, action:action,userName:userName,userType:userType},
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#editModal').modal('hide');
                $('#userName').val(userName);
                $('#userType').val(userType);
                $('#id').val(id);
            }
        })
  });


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

 <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Edit User</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <form method="post" action="">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="userName" class="col-form-label">Username:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control border-danger" id="userName" readonly style="background-color: #2A3038">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="userType" class="col-form-label">User Type:</label>
                        <select class="form-control border-success" id="userType">
                        <option value="user">User</option>
                        <option value="contributor">Contributor</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                  <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="1">
                  <input type="hidden" id="operation" name="operation">
                    <button type="button" id="update" name="update" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have assigned the data into the modal through edit, next thing is to click on update button inside the modal, so you need another jquery code for this....
give a class or id to your update button and do it like this...

```
$(document).on('click', '.update', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $("#id").val();
    var userName = $("#userType").val();
    var userType = $("#userType").val();
    var action = 'update';
    $.ajax({
        url:"/auth/action.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{id:id, action:action,userName:userName,userType:userType},
        success:function(data)
        {
            // Your response from update function....
            // Now hide your modal if you see success response...
            $('#editModal').modal('hide');
        }
    })
  });
```